# JSON.parse is an “undefined” object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I created json with php. Data coming with ajax. But JSON.parse is  giving an “undefined” object. Why ?

Php CODE

```
 $emparray = array();
 while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
     $emparray[] = $row;
 }

 echo json_encode($emparray);
```

Ajax CODE

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/xxx.php/",
        success: function (msg, result, status, xhr) {
            var obj= JSON.parse(msg);
            alert(obj.name);// giving undefined
        },
        error: function (error) {
        }
    });
```

json

```
[{"name":"eng","a":"sdf"}]
```

Comment: because you have an array that has an object in the first index. `obj[0].name`

Comment: obj is an array, try accessing the first element.  `obj[0].name`

Comment: Please, [quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is an array, meaning you'll have to point to the index of the object before accessing the property.

This code should work:

```
console.log(obj[0].name); //Returns "eng"
```

If your JSON array was something like this:

```
[{"name":"eng","a":"sdf"}, {"name":"esp", "a":"abc"}]
```

Then `obj[1].name` would return `"esp"`.

Answer (score 1):

You should `obj[0].name`

Because you are accessing the `name` property of the of the first element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to get data from server

```
$emparray = array();
 while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
     $emparray[] = $row;
 }

 echo json_encode(array("data"=>$emparray));
```

Put all the json response on a key which is `data` here then at front end define that the server response is in JSON by `dataType` and then there is no need to parse data by `JSON.parse()`

`msg.data.length` will provide you the validaton on if the data received from server is empty or not which will prevent the *undefined* error

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/xxx.php/",
        success: function (msg, result, status, xhr) {
            var obj= msg.data;
           if(msg.data.length){       
                  alert(msg.data[0].name);// wll give name at 0 index
              }
        },
        error: function (error) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why is this better?  A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have added explanation